# Cannot build project ionic ios and android

Tags: android, ios, build, ionic-framework

In Windows 10, when I run cmd build iOS and android , it shows the errors below:

[image: https://drive.google.com/a/vivicorp.com/file/d/0BwZKFx415875VXlqcXlEaUQtNkk/view]

How fix these errors?

UPDATE: I haven run build android. Error above, maybe due server download file error.

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Add the required environment variables with the path.

Comment: Ionic build ios will not work because you are working on windows platform and how it will add a ios platform to your project before executing the cmd type ionic platform ls and coming to android first you need to export the environment variable's of Android_sdk than you will resolve your problem's---
if again you face problem means reply with error log

Comment: Thank you! Toward android, I have set the android sdk environment and set PATH but still error as above photo.

Comment: I have added the image to the question. It would help if you added to the text (using [edit]) more information. Copy and paste the text from your command window might be more useful that the screen capture, for example.

Answer (score 1):

## Ionic ios and android

It is simply not possible to develop iPhone/iOS apps on any platform other than a Mac.But have no problem with Android

Downloading gradle from this link **http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip**

paste it in somewhere likes: YourApp\platforms\android\gradle\gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

in buld.js file from YourApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\build.js find this:

```
var distributionUrl = 'distributionUrl=http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';
```

replace this in your own location

```
var distributionUrl = 'distributionUrl=../gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';
```